# Que significa guion bajo

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un código en JavaScript el cual funciona bien, pero me surge una duda, ¿qué significa el guion bajo?:

```js
$(document).on('keyup', ".uppercase", function () {
      $(this).val(function (_, val) {
          return val.toUpperCase();
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="uppercase">
```

Lo que hace el código es convertir el texto escrito en un `input` a mayúsculas, pero dentro del código existe un guión bajo:

```
 $(this).val(function (_, val) {
```

Me gustaría saber que significa o que hace dicho guion.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

En este caso el guion bajo `_` esta siendo usado como nombre de una variable, puedes sustituirlo por una letra y veras que la función sigue haciendo su trabajo perfectamente.

> Un identificador en JavaScript tiene que empezar con una letra, un guión bajo (_) o un símbolo de dólar ($); los valores subsiguientes puede ser números. Debido a que JavaScript diferencia entre mayúsculas y minúsculas, las letras incluyen tanto desde la "A" hasta la "Z" (mayúsculas) como de la "a" hasta la "z".

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Variables

Ejemplo cambiando `_` por `x`

```js
$(document).on('keyup', ".uppercase", function () {
      $(this).val(function (x, val) {
          return val.toUpperCase();
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="uppercase">
```

**Edito** para agregar recomendación de *Bryro*

*Los programadores solemos utilizar `_` simplemente como una variable de omisión; ya que no sera de utilidad o es poco relevante su uso y no es necesario darle una gran referencia o un nombre descriptivo*

Comment: Buen dato, gracias

Comment: Puedes agregar que los programadores solemos utilizarla simplemente como una variable de omision. ya que como no sera de utilidad o relevante su uso no es necesario darle una gran referencia o un nombre descriptivo

Comment: genia gracias..!!

Comment: Comentar también que existe una librería llamada lodash (https://lodash.com) que utiliza el guión bajo como namespace. Tenlo en cuenta si lo ves.